# New-AzureRmVpnClientRootCertificate in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

How can I upload client root certificate with Azure ARM template instead of using Powershell command New-AzureRmVpnClientRootCertificate ? I have the whole environment in a template and that's the only thing missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OSProfile section of the VM, you can put this:

```
"secrets": [
              {
                "sourceVault": {
                  "id": "[parameters('sourceVaultValue')]"
                },
                "vaultCertificates": [
                  {
                    "certificateStore": "[parameters('certificateStoreValue')]",
                    "certificateUrl": "[parameters('certificateUrlValue')]"
                  }
                ]
              }
```

Where source vault value is "/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KVName"

cert store value is My or whichever store you want to use.

cert URL value is "https://KVName.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/CertName/certVersionNumber"

So you obviously need to create a KeyVault and add your cert to it as a secret. You do this by base 64 encoding the cert and uploading that string, like so:

```
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection 
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag)
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes)

$jsonObject = @{
    data = $filecontentencoded
    dataType = 'pfx'
 } | ConvertTo-Json

 $jsonObjectBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jsonObject)
 $jsonEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($jsonObjectBytes)
 $secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $jsonEncoded -AsPlainText -Force

 return $secret
```

where $pfxFilePath and $pwd the path to the cert and pwd is the password.

Then upload with [Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn868050.aspx) -SecretValue $secret (and other params)